# String Constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var a = new String("Hi");

typeof a; // output is "object"

typeof a.constructor  // output is String;
```

But when I am trying to check `a.constructor==String;// output is true`

I think the above statement `(a.constructor==String)`,it should be false as It should be equal to "Hi"

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about what the "constructor" property of an object means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "constructor" property of an object tells you the function that was used to *construct* the object. In

```
new String("Hi")
```

the function involved is the global built-in String constructor. The string `"Hi"` is merely an actual parameter (or, by modern convention, an *argument*) passed to that constructor.

There is no built-in mechanism to access the argument list passed to the constructor function when a particular object was constructed, though an individual constructor implementation is free to track that by its own devices.

Comment: You probably meant *"The string 'Hi' is merely an argument passed to that constructor"*, not a parameter.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado the words "argument" and "parameter" mean more or less the same thing. In fact colloquially they mean exactly the same thing. The *declared* parameters in a function declaration are called the "formal parameters" or "formal arguments", while the values passed in a function call are the "actual parameters" or "actual arguments".

Comment: @GerardoFurtado apparently there is a long tradition of terminological sophistry around those terms on Stackoverflow :) I'm old-school (because I'm old) and in my day the terms were clarified with those "formal" and "actual" modifiers.

Comment: A lot of people use them interchangeably. However, regarding the strict terminology, they seem to be different: [*"Parameters appear in procedure definitions; arguments appear in procedure calls. In the function definition f(x) = x*x the variable x is a parameter; in the function call f(2) the value 2 is the argument of the function."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming))

Comment: Right. Well, I don't know who adjudicates "strict terminology" :)

Comment: I'm also quite old, and because I was a science teacher (biology, not programming) I'm quite rigid regarding terminology... but yes, I've seen that here at S.O. people use those terms as synonyms.

Comment: Ha ha. Yes well over the years I've seen terminology in computing change a lot, and in the JavaScript world it seems to change about every 6 months :) Answer updated.